# Easiest way to CREATE an APP from an Existing Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I already have a facebook page
 http://www.facebook.com/winepassionate

How can I create from there an APP so that i can start using FQL and query various info of the people that LIKE the page?

When I create a new App, i don't see where to put that i want to associate it with this page.

Thanks in advanced,
F.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really "associate" an app with a page. The closest you'll get is an app can become a page tab of the page when you code up the app settings correctly and then add that app as a page tab.

Comment: Is there a tutorial to do so? I already have various likes and would not want to loose them all

Comment: An app is not a page, these are two separate things.  Likes for a current page probably cannot be transferred to your new app.  See here for a tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: So ideally if somebody uses my app to login, i cannot automatically make it like my other page (cause there is no direct association), mainly because they are 2 different and separate things. Is that a true statement?